# How to use a class customization to resolve conflict when generating jaxb object from xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, ifc

When I run the `xjc -d src/ -p com.test IFC2X3.xsd` command on following xsd it gives the conflict.

```
....
<xs:element name="IfcCondenserTypeEnum" nillable="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="ifc:IfcCondenserTypeEnum">
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="ex:instanceAttributes">
                    </xs:attributeGroup>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="IfcCondenserTypeEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="watercooledshelltube">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="watercooledshellcoil">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="watercooledtubeintube">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="watercooledbrazedplate">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="aircooled">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="evaporativecooled">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="userdefined">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="notdefined">
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
   ....
```

Error:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.test.IfcCondenserTypeEnum" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 14912 of file:/media/isuru/Projects/mitrai/bim_exchange/ifc_classes_v2x3/IFC2X3.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "IfcCondenserTypeEnum" is generated from here.
  line 14902 of file:/media/isuru/Projects/mitrai/bim_exchange/ifc_classes_v2x3/IFC2X3.xsd
```

I found some questions regarding this but its not answering this. How can I resolve this as suggested `Use a class customization`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use below binding

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema.xsd">

        <bindings node="//xs:schema//xs:element[@name='IfcCondenserTypeEnum']">
            <class name="CondenserType" />
        </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I am facing similar problem. But I have around 20-30 such variables. Any other solution for this?

Comment: @wib: it is trivial to create a one-off XSLT transform stylesheet which can create these bindings for you. It'll give you all the freedom you need.

Comment: using the binding the and the schema file instead of local file I pointed to the url of the xsd and in the binding I defined binding for only one element it was working

Answer (score -1):

You can use **-autoNameResolution**

For example, you can call `wsdl2java -frontend jaxws21 -impl -server -d ../java -autoNameResolution -p com.yourClass https://webservice.xxxx.com.tr/Sms.asmx?wsdl`

Comment: He asks for xjc, not wsdl2java. Also this was answered and resolved almost 5 years ago.