# How to use a class customization to resolve file generating conflicts

Tags: java, spring, maven, jaxb, wsdl

I am trying to use Maven to generate JAXB files to be used by Spring framework, but Maven displays following errors:

I understand that it is unable to generate files with the names, but I am not sure how to resolve the issue. So far, I visited following links. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969057/how-to-use-a-class-customization-to-resolve-conflict-when-generating-jaxb-object), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409278/generating-java-classes-out-of-xmlschema-xsd-using-jaxb), [3](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/)

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 39; A class/interface with the same name "hello.wsdl.SearchFlights" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
....
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 43; (Relevant to above error) another "SearchFlights" is generated from here.
....
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl; lineNumber: 371; columnNumber: 42; A class/interface with the same name "hello.wsdl.GetFlightDetails" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
....
```

Maven plugin

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
            <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <url>http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl</url>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I added following `package-info.java` file to the `hello.wsdl` package but it did not help.

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "ElsyArres.API",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package hello.wsdl;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?? If yes, how? I am also facing similar issue and I dont want to go ahead with `<arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>` option. I am interested for binding approach.

Comment: for me all I had to do was to remove the package specification <generatePackage>

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The error message you are facing basically states that some names in the the `types`section of your wsdl are used two times. In your case **all** `<element>`tags have the same name as their corresponding types (defined as `<complexType>`).

**Example:**

```
  <s:element name="SearchFlights">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SoapMessage" type="tns:SearchFlights" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

  <s:complexType name="SearchFlights">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="tns:SoapMessageBase">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Request" type="tns:SearchFlightsRequest" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Response" type="tns:SearchFlightsResponse" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
```

This is quite uncommon.

There are basically two options to resolve these issues:

**Use autoNameResolution**

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>0.13.1</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <goals>
                 <goal>generate</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
     <configuration>

         <args>
             <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
         </args>

         <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
         <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
         <schemas>
             <schema>
                 <url>http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl</url>
             </schema>
          </schemas>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The plugin will resolve all naming conflicts through appending numbers to every colliding name. In the above mentioned case of *SearchFlights* this will result in  *SearchFlights* and  *SearchFlights2* being generated.

**A better way** would be to use a binding file to resolve all name conflicts in advance. Binding files mostly contain `XPATH`expression and transformation rules.
A binding file that appends to *every*  declarations name is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl"
            xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='ElsyArres.API']">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jaxb:elementName suffix="Elem"/>
            </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

There are other options for `jaxb:nameXmlTransform` like suffixes and prepending to other kind of xml elements (like types).

Sadly i could not get to work this binding file with the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin`( but i am sure there is a working configuration)

It nevertheless works with the [`org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin`](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) and the following configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <bindingFiles>
         <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
        </bindingFiles>
        <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <vmArgs>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
        </vmArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I am interested for binding approach. Were you able to get working with `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` ??

Comment: `<arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>` works but now I am getting error 
`Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.`
Any suggestions??

Comment: I used the  <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg> solution, and fixed the problem perfectly. Thanks for the solution! spent a day on it.

Comment: wsimport -XautoNameResolution does not work (error!) -B-XautoNameResolution does nothing... :\

Answer (score 33):

If the autoNameResolution fix

```
 <args>
     <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
 </args>
```

doesn't work, try:

```
 <args>
     <arg>-B-XautoNameResolution</arg>
 </args>
```

Comment: thanks, this works also with wsimport utility from jdk

Answer (score 20):

Removing `<generatePackage></generatePackage>` tag solves the problem.

However, the consequence of this removal is that your packages will be created from the xml namespace. For example, the namespace `example.com/xyz` will result to the package `com.example.xyz`

Comment: This does seem like the easiest solution.  Seems to work for me. I wonder what the drawbacks are.

Comment: Exactly, after spending good amount of time able to generate source, would like to know the drawbacks of it.

Answer (score 7):

Removing generatePackage as hamid-mohayeji mentions fixes a lot of cases (at least cases where your xsds are sane). The setting tries to put all entities into the same namespace and that's bound to go wrong in non-simple cases. However omitting the package leaves you with packages created from the namespace. For example http://www.co.com/srvc/api/common would become package *com.co.srvc.api.common*.

This can be remedied by adding a simple binding file. Configure `<bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>` in the pom and add a binding file something.xjb to the binding directory. Here you need to refer to individual relatively to this file.

This file sets packages for each xsd-file individually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/common.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.mycomp.myapp.co.common" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    ... more bindings

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for xsd to jaxb and using jaxb2-maven-plugin from org.codehaus.mojo. There was a packageName under configuration creates all the generated files under the same package caused the issue

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaFiles>test.xsd</schemaFiles>
        <!-- <packageName>com.example.myschema</packageName> -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're using

```
jaxws-maven-plugin
```

maven plugin to generate classes from WSDL use below arguments to resolve this issue.

```
<execution>
 <configuration>
    <xjcArgs>
        <xjcArg>-XautoNameResolution</xjcArg>
    </xjcArgs>
 </configuration>
</execution>
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above didnt worked...

**But this:**

```
<configuration>
  <defaultOptions>
    <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
  </defaultOptions>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <defaultOptions>
        <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
</defaultOptions>
```

This worked for me for Apache CXF Plugin.